# Are "NLT" and "NMT" acronyms generally used in sentences?

Tags: word-usage

I found that "NLT (not less than)" and "NMT (not more than)" acronyms are frequently used in many scientific journals.
Since English is not my mother tongue, I was wondering if they are widely used terms for people in english speaking countries. If it is not, is it necessary to add a description for NLT and NMT to explain what they mean; e.g. NLT stands for 'not less than'.

Comment: I can't say that I'm familiar with them.  I might be able to figure them out from context, or might not.

Answer (score 3):

These are not commonly known acronyms in general usage.

> is it necessary to add a description for NLT and NMT to explain what they mean; e.g. NLT stands for 'not less than'.

In a paper written for one of the journals where these abbreviations are common, it might not be. Check the style guide for the journal you are submitting to.

In any other context, you would need to explain them.

Comment: I had certainly never heard of either of these acronyms until just now. In mathematical contexts, the closest I've heard is LT (less than) and GT (greater than).